# Does JSch implement SFTP inherently?

Tags: java, sftp, checksum, jsch, md5sum

This is not a duplicate of [How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056566/how-to-perform-checksums-during-a-sftp-file-transfer-for-data-integrity) as I am more looking for the details of JSch and how it implements SFTP. If it implements SFTP, then as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216902/getting-md5-checksum-on-the-remote-server-using-jsch), there is no need to do file checksum.

My problem statement is: For pulling files from remote SFTP location, we are using JSch library. We have been asked to ensure file integrity during the transfer.

The `com.jcraft.jsch.Channel` object has been created as

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
```

Does creating an object of `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSFTP` ensure that SFTP is implemented properly? The reason I ask is I couldn't find any proper justification around it. If it doesn't, can someone help me how can I determine the remote file `checksum` before the start of the transfer?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you could examine the packets with wireshark

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am afraid I cannot get this tool installed..

Comment: If you can not trust SFTP (or any protocol, for that matter) to properly transfer the file, and given that most protocols won't allow you to execute remote code for computing a hash, the simple recipes apply : e.g. 1) have the checksum in the name of the file, or 2) have a metadatafile just next to the file to retreive, and download it to check integrity, or 3) use a data format that inherently uses a checksum (anywhere from a digitally signed file in a PKCS7 format to a simple CRC-32 checksumed format like ZIP).

Comment: @ScaryWombat: AFAIK wireshark can't decrypt SSH (after KEX) and therefore you wouldn't be able to usefully look at SFTP activity that way.